# how to speed up magento2 with redis?

Tags: magento2.2

I am using magento2 , but its page load time max than  4s.

have alread config  useing  varnish .

after config use redis , there are still huge sql query at catalog page ？  why ?  how to speed up this page ?

redis config is : app/etc/env.php

```
 'cache' => array(
    'frontend' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => array(
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379',
            ),
        ),
        'page_cache' => array(
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => array(
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

=======================
catalog page query is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvbaK.png)

Comment: Redis and Varnish are good caching technologies that Magento 2 supports out of the box. Although caching speeds up the website but the effect last until it expires. I recommend to run Magento 2 profiler to find the actual cause of slowness and fix it. Here is the link that you can follow: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html

Comment: Thank you, but cannot execute the command follow the document .
I am using magento2.25, the error is :
$ bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html 


                                                                  
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                      
  There are no commands defined in the "dev:profiler" namespace.  
  Did you mean one of these?

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Magento2 profiler following below steps:

1. Set environment variable: MAGE_PROFILER = html. Refer to [this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-how-to-set.html).
2. Enable/Set Magento2 developer mode

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
   ```
3. [Clear the cache.](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-clear-cache.html) OR You can disable the cache for time being.
4. Open the website in browser incognito(private) window. Browse to the slow webpage & check at the bottom, you will see the profiler stack trace showing calls and time taken.